# @springBatchTest with no datasource Error

Tags: spring-batch

when i want to use @springBatchTest annotation without having a datasource in the project i get this error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDatasource'
```

Is there a way to tell @SpringBatchTest Annotation to only create **JobLauncherTestUtils** and not the **JobRepositoryTestUtils** or another solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `@SpringBatchTest`, it is expected that the test context contains a bean of type `DataSource`. This is mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/context/SpringBatchTest.html) of the annotation, here is an excerpt:

```
It should be noted that JobLauncherTestUtils requires a Job bean
and that JobRepositoryTestUtils requires a DataSource bean. Since
this annotation registers a JobLauncherTestUtils and a JobRepositoryTestUtils 
in the test context, it is expected that the test context contains
a single autowire candidate for a Job and a DataSource
```

If all you need is a `JobLauncherTestUtils` but not other test utilities, you can define a `JobLauncherTestUtils` bean manually in your test class, something like:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncherTestUtils testUtils() {
    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(jobUnderTest);
    return jobLauncherTestUtils;
}
```

Comment: Could you pls guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164606/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-org-springframework-batch-core-configuration-annotat/77164864#77164864?