# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration annotation.JobBuilderFactory' available: in Junit

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-test

I went through below few links already, but did not turn to be working, I'm using Spring Boot v2.7.1 and Batch and has below code and using junit 5.

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/testing.html#creatingUnitTestClass
- [No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected single matching bean but found 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150048/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-org-springframework-batch-core-job-available-expec)

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

JUnit

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JobConfiguration.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, 
  DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class XmlFileOutputApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobId", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).addDate("date", new Date())
                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);
        System.out.println(jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }
}
```

JobConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> customerPagingItemReader(){
        // Sort Keys
        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
        sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);

        // MySQL implementation of a PagingQueryProvider using database specific features.
        MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("id, firstName, lastName, birthdate");
        queryProvider.setFromClause("from customer");
        queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

        return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Customer>()
                .name("customerPagingItemReader")
                .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                .fetchSize(1000)
                .rowMapper(new CustomerRowMapper())
                .queryProvider(queryProvider)
                .build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter() throws Exception{
        String customerOutputPath = File.createTempFile("customerOutput", ".out").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(">> Output Path = "+customerOutputPath);

        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);

        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAliases(aliases);

        return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .name("customerItemWriter")
                .rootTagName("customers")
                .marshaller(marshaller)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(customerOutputPath))
                .build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(100)
                .reader(customerPagingItemReader())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
}
```

MainApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class XmlFileOutputApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XmlFileOutputApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobId", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .addDate("date", new Date())
                .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("STATUS :: "+execution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory` beans are defined by `@EnableBatchProcessing`.

But now as you explicitly configure the spring test to load the context from the `JobConfiguration` , the `XmlFileOutputApplication` will never be picked up as the configuration class and hence the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotated on it does not have any effect.

The easy way to fix it is to make sure you include `@EnableBatchProcessing` on any configuration classes that the spring test will load.  You can do it by :

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JobConfiguration.class })
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class XmlFileOutputApplicationTests {

}
```

or annotating `@EnableBatchProcessing` on `JobConfiguration` :

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JobConfiguration.class })
public class XmlFileOutputApplicationTests {

}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: Now getting 
```Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.```

Comment: that means my answer can solve the original issue. this is another issue. thinks that you the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` somehow cannot be activated. Can you set the logger `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure` to debug and check with the auto-configuration report to see what happen?

Comment: I tried several options, but no luck, also spring doc section for testing is confusing , can you please try ?

Comment: consider to offer bounties for this question ? happy to do further investigate if it has

Comment: Will do for sure, currently bounty eligible for tomorrow, will do, but for me must to investigate. Many thanks